# The extension of the ring morphism of fields under algebraic closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Suppose $l: k \to K$ is a ring morphism and $\bar k$, $\bar K$ are the algebraic closure respectively, is there exist a ring morphism $\bar l:\bar k \to \bar K$ such that the diagram

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
k @>{l}>> K
\\
@VVV @VVV
\\
{\overline k} @>{\overline l}>> {\overline K}
\end{CD}
$$

commutes?

Comment: I've edited your question in accordance with my now deleted comment; make sure it's still your original question. Also: What've you tried?

Comment: Thanks. I try to use the universal property of algebraic closure, but since $l$ is just embedding, not the inclusion, it seems weird.

Comment: What is the universal property of the algebraic closure? Not sure if I know what you mean by that. In future, you should add such details/ideas to your post (you can now with an [edit]).

Comment: it says if $K/F$, $E/F$ are field extension and if $E$ algebraic over $F$, $K$ is algebraically closed, then there exists an $F$-embedding from $E$ to $K$

Comment: Do you know anything else about this $F$-embedding $E\hookrightarrow K$? Like, how it's constructed or what properties it satisfies. Abstractly, this universal property (if you insist on calling it that) only gives you *some* field homomorphism $\overline k\to\overline K$ but not necessarily one compatible with $l\colon k\to K$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly you are asking if any field homomorphism $l\colon k\to K$ can be extended to a field homomorphism $\overline l\colon \overline k\to\overline K$ for some algebraic closures $\overline k$ and $\overline K$ of $k$ and $K$, respectively.

If so, the answer is yes. This is an exercise in Zorn's Lemma (you may find a proof [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/zorn2.pdf)). For this you only need that $\overline K$ is an algebraically closed field admitting a field homomorphism $k\to\overline K$ (by embedding the image of $l$ in $\overline K$).